# Shopify CLI - shopify node serve doesn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify

I created a node app with

```
shopify create node
```

It's creating the app on my dev-store and provides boilerplate react/node-project.
When I start a dev server with

```
shopify node serve
```

it gives me the install-link, starts the dev-server and the ngrok tunnel. I follow the link, I get presented with the install/permissions-screen. I confirm the install and the site loads forever, stays blank and I get this in console:

[image: Console errors at install]

However, if I check the apps in the dev-store, the app shows as installed.

When I click on the app to open it, the site loads forever again and I get this in the console:

[image: Console errors at open app]

I'm on Windows10, using Powershell to run the shopify-cli.

Comment: Hey @Fabian Mallmann, Did you get any workaround for this?

Comment: I sometimes randomly get this problem, but on linux. I solved it by updating `shopify-cli`, and reauthenticate with ngrok.